# Python or GDAL equivalent to ArcPy GetParameterasText

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is any equivalent to `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` in Python and/or GDAL (not using ArcPy). I would like to create a script that prompts a window asking for a file location (as when you add a script into ArcGIS) where you can navigate and select the file. I guess I could use a raw_input and just write a file path, but I would like something more interactive.

Comment: Not really a GIS question, but you could look into PyQt: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/

Comment: Yes, raw_input.  There is a Python library called EasyGUI that will give you a simple dialog box to enter a file location.  Of course, if you want to share your script the end-user would also need to install EasyGUI or you could make a standalone Python executable using something like py2exe.   http://easygui.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It is a pure Python question: [Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog)